# How can I handle large decimals in python?

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

I'm parsing through a list of data. The data is a list of values, and they are very big with many decimal points. For example:

```
-3.21446735874, 48.4505248207, 0.
-3.21476825075, 48.4504325609, 0.
```

I need to be able to use these numbers in calculations without python reducing the precision of each number and its size (`float(x)` and `int(x)` obviously don't work!). I have tried the `decimal` module, but apparently it can't be used any more due to a non-functioning import or something. I'd prefer the solution to be platform independent (only using the default python modules please!).

Comment: "I have tried the decimal module, but apparently it can't be used any more due to a non-functioning import or something" - say what?

Comment: "apparently it can't be used anymore" - please elaborate. `decimal` *is* a default Python module, and it's platform independent.

Comment: Did you happen to name your Python script `decimal.py`? What do you mean by "non-functioning import"?

Comment: It's hard to understand what's wrong with the `decimal` module solution.  Could you explain why?

Comment: I can't imagine another reason for this to fail.  `decimal.py` is also a reasonable name for a script so it's a very believable mistake.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RoutePlot.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(decimal(1) / decimal(7))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue

Comment: @BarrySmith please post the code that you're running.  It sounds like you're trying to use a module object as a function.  You can likely just change `decimal` to `decimal.Decimal` and be ok.

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to call the `decimal` module directly, instead use `decimal.Decimal`. `decimal` is a module object which contains attributes like `Decimal`, `'DefaultContext'` etc, to access these attributes use the dot notation (`decimal.attr_name`).

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('1.234')
Decimal('1.234')
>>> decimal.DefaultContext
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999999, Emax=999999999, capitals=1, flags=[], traps=[Overflow, InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero])
```

You can also import selected attributes into the current namespaces using the `from decimal import ..` syntax:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, DecimalTuple  #import two attrs in current namespace
>>> Decimal('1.234')  #now use it directly, no dot notation required
Decimal('1.234')
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have a [bigfloat](http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/) package

> The bigfloat package is a Python wrapper for the GNU MPFR library for arbitrary-precision floating-point reliable arithmetic.

You can work with precision you want.