# How to store a decimal number in python of required precision with suffixed zeros?

Tags: python

Notice the below results in python interpreter.

```
>>> b=245.353
>>> print('%.50f'%b)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000
```

After the 14th decimal place, numbers other than zeros start appearing and they remain until 44th place.

> Python documentation in *Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations* mentions this limitation but the solutions mentioned in the documentation doesn't work for some cases as explained below.

**To test how it affects the results of arithmetic operations with `b`, I tried some multiplications.**

Multiplying 5.132435246464... with the value of b shown by python upto 50 decimal places.

```
>>> print('%.50f'%(5.132435246464363423432432432342432324342*245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000))
1259.25838502577107647084631025791168212890625000000000
```

Multiplying 5.132435246464... with b

```
>>> print('%.50f'%(5.132435246464363423432432432342432324342*b))
1259.25838502577107647084631025791168212890625000000000
```

Multiplying 5.132435246464... with 245.353

```
>>> print('%.50f'%(5.132435246464363423432432432342432324342*245.353))
1259.25838502577107647084631025791168212890625000000000
```

> All the 3 results are exactly the same.

**To check the true results, I wrote a program to multiply 2 numbers digit by digit as done on pen and paper to not loose accuracy. It is slow but accurate.**

> Now doing the same calculations with my program -

Multiplying 5.132435246464... with the value of b shown by python upto 50 decimal places

```
5.132435246464363423432432432342432324342 * 245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000 
= 1259.25838502577100337468290116624347509546633362424989047667622799053788185119628906250000000
```

multiplying 5.132435246464... with 245.353

```
5.132435246464363423432432432342432324342 * 245.35300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
= 1259.25838502577095902941759457251279807428272600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Both the results are different from each other as well as from the results of previous 3 operations.

**The results start to differ at 14th decimal place.**

> The documentation suggests to use Decimal and Fraction libraries.

> Fraction Library

```
>>> g = Fraction('245.353')
>>> g
Fraction(245353, 1000)
>>> print('%.50f'%g)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000
```

Being more explicit didn't help.

```
>>> g = Fraction('245.35300000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
>>> g
Fraction(245353, 1000)
>>> print('%.50f'%g)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000
```

> Same thing happens with Decimal library

```
>>> d = Decimal('245.353')
>>> d
Decimal('245.353')
>>> print('%.50f'%d)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000
```

Being more explicit

```
>>> d = Decimal('245.353000000000000000000000000000000000')
>>> d
Decimal('245.353000000000000000000000000000000000')
>>> print('%.50f'%d)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000
```

This severely affects a applied numerical math program.

- How can 245.353000000000000 (more than 14 decimal places) be stored in python?

Comment: it's result is  decimal approximation to the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored by the machine. [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Yes, documentation states that. The main issue is how to get required precision? Sorry for including why non-zero digits appear as part of the question. I have edited it out.

Comment: you need to use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) set the precision context, [handle large decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466016/how-can-i-handle-large-decimals-in-python)  , [python high decimal precision handling](https://zetcode.com/python/decimal/)

Comment: @sahasrara62 there are 2 answers there. The second answer suggests using `bigfloat` library which needs to be installed. The first answer doesn't seem to solve my problem or maybe I'm unable to understand how it solves it? Can you please tell a bit more specifically
Edit: I have imported like this `from decimal import Decimal`. I don't think I'm calling module as a function as the person did in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466016/how-can-i-handle-large-decimals-in-python.

Comment: in 3rd link there are example where you can set precision context, it is same as first one, you can see this one for implementing first one

Comment: I tried this


>>> decimal.prec=100
>>> ee=decimal.Decimal('245.353000000000000000000000000000000000')
>>> print('%.50f'%ee)
245.35300000000000864019966684281826019287109375000000

If this is what you meant then it didn't work. If possible can you write a working solution as an answer or mention a resource explaining the same?

Comment: You can’t use `%f` to **display** such values accurately: it converts them to the ordinary `float` type!